# Python stompest unable to connect to ActiveMQ over SSL

Tags: python, ssl, activemq-classic, stomp

I am trying to connect to an ActiveMQ message broker which uses SSL. I am getting the error:

```
invalid uri: ssl://myserver.com:61613 [invalid broker(s): 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groupdict']
```

Example code taken from stompest documentation: I only changed server, user and pass:

```
import time
from stompest.config import StompConfig
from stompest.sync import Stomp

while True:
    try:
        client = Stomp(StompConfig("ssl://myserver.com:61613", login = 'me', passcode = 'me', version = "1.2" ))
        client.connect(versions = ["1.2"], host = vhost, heartBeats = (0, 60000))   #CONNECT
        subscription = client.subscribe(destination, {"ack": "client", "id": "0"})  #SUBSCRIBE
        while True:
            frame = client.receiveFrame()
            try:
                print frame.body
                client.ack(frame)   #ACK
            except:
                print "Error: Can't handle message received, NACKing"
                client.nack(frame)  #NACK
    except Exception, e:
        # Reconnect on exception
        print "Exception handled, reconnecting...\nDetail:\n%s" % e
        try:
            client.disconnect()
        except:
            pass
        time.sleep(5)
```

I believe Stompest can handle SSL, but I can't find any reference in the documentation.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your `StompConfig` has to be provided with an [`SSLContext`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html#ssl.SSLContext) with a configuration of the SSL connection. Exactly how this one should look will depend on the specifics of your setup, so let us have a look at some of the options.

For more information on how to set up ActiveMQ to use SSL in general, see [this Apache guide](https://activemq.apache.org/how-do-i-use-ssl.html), and [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46770328/activemq-stompssl-with-python-stomp-client/) which addresses the same issue but for [`stomp.py`](https://github.com/jasonrbriggs/stomp.py).

## No validation

If all you need is a quick and dirty connection with no validation of broker or client -- that is, a connection which would be susceptible to MITM attacks from an active attacker -- then you can supply an `SSLContext` with validation disabled:

```
import ssl
sslContext = ssl.create_default_context(ssl.Purpose.SERVER_AUTH)
# Let's at least disable some of the older SSL protocols
sslContext.options |= ssl.OP_NO_TLSv1 | ssl.OP_NO_TLSv1_1 | ssl.OP_NO_SSLv3
sslContext.check_hostname = False
sslContext.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE
```

With this, all you need to do is to provide `sslContext` to your `StompConfig`:

```
client = Stomp(StompConfig('ssl://myserver.com:61613', login='me', passcode='me', version='1.2', sslContext=sslContext))
```

## Broker certificate validation

The first improvement over this would be to verify the certificate provided by the server. Assuming that you are using a self-signed certificate (as opposed to one signed by a certificate authority), you can simply provide your `SSLContext` with the certificate directly:

First, on the broker, export the certificate from its keystore, which we will assume is stored in a file called `broker.ks` by using the Java `keytool` through

```
keytool -exportcert -rfc -alias broker -keystore broker.ks -file broker.pem
```

Now, move `broker.pem` to the Python client and change the `sslContext` configuration as follows:

```
sslContext = ssl.create_default_context(cafile='broker.pem')
sslContext.check_hostname = True
sslContext.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_REQUIRED
```

## Client certificate validation

ActiveMQ servers can also be set up to only allow connections from clients with predefined certificates. Assuming that you have a PEM encoded client certificate in `client.pem`, have stored the private key in `client.key` (cf. e.g. the first part of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50774783/5085211)), and set up ApacheMQ to validate that certificate (cf. the third part of the same answer), then all you need to do to have `stompest` use that pair for the connection is to call

```
sslContext.load_cert_chain('client.pem', 'client.key')
```

as part of the configuration.