# What certificates does an Artemis AMQ subscriber using stomp.py need to establish a SSL connection to server

Tags: python, ssl, stomp, activemq-artemis, amq

I am using stomp.py to establish a Stomp1.2 SSL connection to a `ActiveMQ-Artemis/2.7.0.redhat-00056 ActiveMQ Artemis Messaging Engine`. I have no control over the server and I was given the following instructions. (I am the Subscriber referred to below.)

> Other party will provide a Trust Store file, a Certificate file and a pair of User ID and Password to each Subscriber. Depending on the subscriber system’s requirement, the subscriber might need to import the Certificate file into its server Certificate Store or Subscriber might need to embed the Trust Store file into its connection coding.

1. Do I need any AMQ/Artemis configurations to embed the certificates? Or can I just pass in the required files through the `set_ssl` method found in http://jasonrbriggs.github.io/stomp.py/stomp.html#module-stomp.connect?
2. The files I received were `broker_cert.cer.txt` and `client.ts`. I am not sure how to use them. I have seen the answer in https://stackoverflow.com/a/50774783/16235794 and it make it sound like I would need to generate the `.key` and `.pem` files. But if I am generating the files, how exactly is the other party supposed to verify them? What files should I be receiving from the other party for authentication purposes?

Answer (score 0):

The [stomp.py](https://github.com/jasonrbriggs/stomp.py) library doesn't validate the server certificate by default so invoking the `set_ssl` method just with the server address should work, ie:

```
conn.set_ssl([('127.0.0.1', 62614)])
```

Invoke the `set_ssl` method with the PEM server certificate to validate the server certificate, ie:

```
conn.set_ssl([('localhost', 62614)], ca_certs='broker_cert.pem')
```

Use the keytoot tool to export the PEM server certificate from the `client.ts` trust store or request it to the other party.

```
keytool -keystore server-client.ts -storepass <STORE_PASSWORD> -alias <ALIAS> -exportcert -rfc > broker_cert.pem
```

See [test_ssl.py](https://github.com/jasonrbriggs/stomp.py/blob/dev/tests/test_ssl.py) for further details.

Comment: So setting `ca_certs` didn't work. I am seeing this error - ` Could not connect to host HOST, port PORT`. Also, `broker_cert.cer.txt` is columns of alphanumeric text. That's different from a `.pem` file. Should the other party give me a `.pem` file?

Comment: I guess `broker_cert.cer.txt` file is not a PEM certificate. Use the keytoot tool to export the PEM server certificate from the client.ts trust store or request it to the other party. See my updated answer for further details.

Comment: Thanks for the command. Is the `-storepass` supposed to be given by the other party? And I am not sure what the `alias` should be in this case. Can I choose any `alias` I want?

Comment: The stores can include multiple certificates so you need an alias to identify them. The other party should provide the alias and the password used to create the `client.ts` trust store. Maybe your store has no password so remove the `-storepass` parameter and use the `-list` command to see the aliases and certificates included in  the store, ie `keytool -v -list -keystore client.ts`. An alternative tool with the GUI is [KeyStore Explorer][https://keystore-explorer.org/].

Comment: Thanks! I will explore these options.

Comment: Hi. Sorry no updates yet. Will probably not get to it for a couple more weeks.